# Someone else is taking credit for my suggest edit

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits

Okay, it goes like this. A user had posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21907663/mvc-4-view-to-create-a-model-with-a-list-of-another-model/21908042#21908042). I edited it. Some other user undoes that edit. Finally, question shows edited version of mine but the other user's name is shown as edited person. I have checked the edit revision, it shows **'Rollback to Revision 2'** as final status. Revision 2 was my edit. But my question is why is he credited for it? Check the below link:

[Edit Revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21907663/revisions).

Comment: Mmmm como estas someone else

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The other user initially rolled back to the original version and later realized that your edit was proper and thus rolled it back to revision 2 which was suggested by you. The user did not take your credit away by any means. The revision history still shows that revision 2 was suggested by you and you even have your `+2 reputation` got from editing the post.

[image: Credit for the edit]

It is just that the post always shows the name of the most recent editor but that doesn't mean that user got the credit for your edit or took away your edit.

Answer (score 6):

By *credit* if you mean the name of the last editor of the post like this:

> [image]

The rollback is also an edit. The post show the editor of the last revision. If someone rollback an edit that means (s)he has changed something in the last edit.

By *credit* if you mean +2 reputation, then as [@Ɍ.Ɉ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222380/187824) said user with 2k+ reputation or who rollback an edit do not get any credits.

Answer (score -3):

It happened to me - I made a nice edit on StackOverflow that I think noticeably improved the post, and someone came in right after and moved 1 space, and now he is getting the visibility for the update.

Yes, it's a small and minor detail, but if I'm being honest .. it does leave a bit of a bad taste.

Anyway, as they say - " don't sweat the small stuff " .. I just mention this here to add to the thread another example of this sort of side-effect in getting credit for a contribution; and that it does have some impact on morale.

One possible consequence is that some folks may be less inclined to make edits if they know someone can quickly eclipse their efforts .. especially if they like to get the credit for making a worthwhile contribution; which I'm guessing is the case for at least a few of us who participate in these communities ?! ;)

So you know how Edits need to be approved by other members .. One idea for a solution to this situation is: *there could be a second approval to determine who's name should be connected to the Last-Editor spot on a post.*

Anyway, just my $0.02.  I really appreciate the Stack service and community - they help me with my work every day and a lot!  So if someone gets some credit from me .. I honestly don't mind.  I'm glad the platform is as effective as it is and that I can participate - Thanks Stack!

Comment: If you look at revision 4, its not just 'moved 1 space' - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14116919/revisions but also some rewording and cleanup of other line breaks.

Comment: So, not to split hairs.. but just in terms of "quantity & quality" I feel my edits there had more impact than the changes that came afterward.  And beyond that, even if my example isn't the best one, I think this discussion illustrates that a legit. scenario - as described, can indeed occur.. No?

Comment: does it *really* matter who the last name that shows up on an edit is?

Comment: And I think it's interesting I got dinged on points with down votes for expressing an honest perspective and experience here... it's not like I posted an answer I claimed was correct.  But I guess it's just par for the course :)

Comment: to some people maybe it does matter .. otherwise, I don't think this thread would have gone as far as it has.  It's a meta consideration I would say .. And for the record, I do start out my post with "don't sweat the small stuff"

Comment: The post expresses the confusion about the 'last edited by and when' and 'edit credits to'.  My IDE shows who last checked in a given file - it doesn't mean they have credit for all the edits in the file nor that they wrote it. Looking at revisions is a content management history.

Comment: Now that I have seen my score climb a few hundred points, I have to admit - when I sign on in the morning, one of the 1st things I'm curious about is.. did I get some points because I posted something helpful. I feel a tad guilty about the ego aspect, but it's the reality. StackOverflow has got me pulled in, in the way Facebook or other social sites would like me to be genuinely engaged & enthused about updates to my experience there.

Comment: So from the perspective of StackOverflow "Individualistic" UX, I think personal presence & visibility could be a non-trivial consideration for some.. in addition to and beyond the practical considerations for looking at version history to see who did what.  Yes, I guess my post deviates a bit from the specifics of the original question, but I think this is relevant .. and I didn't see any other posts with this discussion already.